# Insert NULL into a TSQL date from PHP

Tags: php, t-sql, date, insert, null

I need to insert in my TSQL table  a NULL value in a date field.

When I'm building the query from my php I do:

```
       if (!is_null($object->getDate()))
        {
            $sSql .=" @Date =  '".$object->getDate()."',";   
        }
         else
        {
            $sSql .=" @Date =NULL,";

        }
```

But this inserts 01/01/1900 0:00:00 instead of NULL

The column is datetime null, and in the procedure:

```
AND (@Date IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date, 102) = MYDB.dbo.MYTABLE.Date)
```

I'm setting the date like this:

```
$objet->setDate(NULL);
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does your `$object->getDate()` definitely return nulls and not zeros? Is your column `not null default 0`?

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but can you simply skip adding the date field if there's no data to add? And let the database insert the default value in there for you?

Comment: datetime null, and in the procedure:    AND (@Date IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date, 102) = MYDB.dbo.MYTABLE.Date)

Comment: Andrewsi not a silly question, probably I'm making a basic mistake. I set the date like this:$object->setDate(NULL);

Comment: I've updated the post with this info, thanks

Comment: according to the php documentation a datetime type is returned... does null value has a sense for php datetime type ? WHere do you read the value : in SSMS or as an output of some php code ?

Comment: The my table's field shows 01/01/1900 0:00:00 instead of null in the database

Comment: Rup, your comment helped me to solve my problem. Could you please write it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot!